# Anybody know how to implement 'Optimal global and adaptive thresholding?

Tags: image, image-processing, emgucv

Does anyone know how to implement'Optimal global and adaptive thresholding' algo?

If know, can please share with me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Otsu's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method) method for choosing the global threshold based on image histogram.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int OtsuThreshold(double[] histogram)
{
    double pr1, pr2, pr;
    int t = 0;
    double[] vet = new double[255];

    double major = -1;
    //int idx;
    for (int k = 1; k < Util.GrayLevels-1; k++)
    {                
        pr1 = HistogramProbability(0, k, histogram);
        pr2 = HistogramProbability(k + 1, Util.MaxGrayLevel, histogram);
        pr=pr1*pr2;
        if(pr==0) pr=1;

        double result = Math.Pow((ImageMean(0, k, histogram) * pr2) - (ImageMean(k + 1, Util.MaxGrayLevel, histogram) * pr1), 2) / pr;
        if (result > major)
        {
            major = result;
            t = k;
        }
    }

    //t = IMaior(vet,Util.GrayLevels);
    return t;
}        


public double HistogramProbability(int start, int end, double[] histogram)
{
    if (start < 0 || end > histogram.Length)
        return 0;

    double p = 0;
    for (int i = start; i < end; ++i)
        p += histogram[i];

    return p;
}


public double ImageMean(int start, int end, double[] histogram)
{
    double mean = 0;

    if (start < 0 || end > histogram.Length) return 0;

    for (int i = start; i < end; i++)
    {
        mean += i * histogram[i];
    }

    return mean;
}
```

Sorry, I know there's a lot of source code here and some methods may be missing but if you follow it I'll see its not all that hard. Unfortunately I'm re-inventing the wheel (not using any library) but I hope the source here can help you write it in your language of choice.

This [link](http://wiki.robojackets.org/w/Adaptive_Thresholding#Otsu_Thresholding) can be useful

Also, if you have a library nearby (engineering or CS material) I recommend [this book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0780334108). It explain in a clear way how Otsu method works.

Regards